# How can i move a small text on 2 lines, without using 1 div only

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How can I make "This text" to be on 2 lines, and center it next to the circle, also put the arrow between first and second circle

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wfVy.png

```
<div className="steps">
    <div className="circle">
        <div className="step-number">{number}</div>
    </div>
    <div className="step-text">This text</div>
    <div>{ shouldRenderArrow && <Icon className="arrow" name="ArrowDownward" /> }</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is the current CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Some change require in your div and some styling need then you got.

```css
.steps{
    display: flex;
 }
 
 .circle {
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 50px;
    float: left;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
 }
 
 .step-text {
     align-self: self-start;
    justify-self: start;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 6px;
    padding-top: 6px;
 }
 .arrow{
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 11px;
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: flex-end;
    height:25px
 }
 .circle-arrow {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
 }
```

```html
<div class="steps">
      <div class="circle-arrow">
      <div class="circle">
        <div class="step-number">1</div>
      </div>
      
      <Icon class="arrow" name="ArrowDownward" /> 
    </div>
      <div class="step-text">This text</div>
    
</div>
<div class="steps">
      <div class="circle-arrow">
      <div class="circle">
        <div class="step-number">2</div>
      </div>
      
      <Icon class="arrow" name="ArrowDownward" /> 
    </div>
      <div class="step-text">This text</div>
    
</div>
<div class="steps">
      <div class="circle-arrow">
      <div class="circle">
        <div class="step-number">3</div>
      </div>
     </div>
      <div class="step-text">This text</div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: I have no arrow image therefor I use the width and height for arrow when you use real image you need to remove width and height form .arrow div in css.